# Display the client IP address when an error occurs in SSLServer # accept

Tags: ruby, ssl

I made an TCP server with ruby. The versions are below.

- ruby 2.3.1p112
- openssl 2.0.4

The code is below.

```
context             = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
context.cert        = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(CERT_PATH))
context.key         = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(KEY_PATH))
context.ca_file     = CERT_PATH
context.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
tcp_server          = TCPServer.new(PORT)
@ssl_server         = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(tcp_server, context)

loop do
  Thread.abort_on_exception = true
  begin
    Thread.start(@ssl_server.accept) do |socket|
      do_something
      socket.close
    end
  rescue => e
    ERROR_LOGGER.error e
    exit
  end
end
```

Basically it works fine, but the following error occasionally occurs when `@ssl_server.accept` is executed.

`E, [2018-03-02T11:06:10.142500 #10116] ERROR -- : SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read client key exchange A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

I would like to know who is accessing this error. Therefore, I would like to display the ip address of the access source when an error occurs. Please tell me who knows how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Socket#accept`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-i-accept) returns socket descriptor and `addr_info`, so you might do something like:

```
loop do
  Thread.abort_on_exception = true
  begin
    _fd, @addr_info = @ssl_server.accept
    Thread.start(_fd) do |socket|
      do_something
      socket.close
    end
  rescue => e
    ERROR_LOGGER.error e
    ERROR_LOGGER.info "AddrInfo: #{@addr_info}"
    exit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried moving it using the code block that you got for me. However, it will result in the following error in `accept` execution.

`undefined local variable or method ’_'`

I am investigating errors, but please let me know if you already know the cause.

Comment: In that case, it will be `undefined local variable or method ’_fd'`.

Comment: Just find out how to get `addr_info` from what `accept` returned, I have provided the reference.

Comment: I successfully wrote `_fd, @addr_info = @ssl_server.accept \n Thread.start(_fd) do |socket|` instead of `Thread.start(_fd, @addr_info = @ssl_server.accept) do |socket|`